# Juliaのfor文内で，ファイル名をその都度変更する方法について

Tags: julia

Juliaのfor文を回して画像ファイルの名前を自動で変更して保存したい場合はどのように記述するのでしょうか？
例えば

```
    using GraphPlots
    using LightGraphs
    m = 10
    G = LightGraphs.SimpleGraph(m)
    graph_plot = gplot(G)

    for i in 1:n
        draw(PNG("i.png", 50cm, 50cm), graph_plot)
    end
```

のdraw関数内のiを変更させながら画像を連続で保存したいです。どのように行えば良いでしょうか。ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Comment: 例えば `for` 文を使わない場合であればリネームする記述をする事はできるのでしょうか？ / "投げやりですみません" よりも、途中まででも自分で試したことを質問に含めた方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: この記事 [JuliaとMatplotlibでグラフを作る際のハマりポイントとサンプルプログラム集](https://www.eureka-moments-blog.com/entry/2020/09/06/102455) の`各ファイル名は、1始まりの連番.pngとなるようにする`あたりが参考になるでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Printf.@sprintf](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/#Printf.@sprintf) を使います。以下のコードでは整数値(`i`)を 2 桁 zero padding の文字列に変換しています。

```
using GraphPlot
using LightGraphs
using Cairo, Compose
using Printf

m = 10
G = LightGraphs.SimpleGraph(m)
graph_plot = gplot(G)

for i in 1:m
  draw(PNG(@sprintf("%02d.png", i), 50cm, 50cm), graph_plot)
end
```

とは言うものの、作成される画像(`01.png`〜`10.png`)は全て同じ内容になっています。思うに、以下の様になるのではないでしょうか？

```
using GraphPlot
using LightGraphs
using Cairo, Compose
using Printf

m = 10
for i in 1:m
  graph_plot = gplot(LightGraphs.SimpleGraph(i))
  draw(PNG(@sprintf("%02d.png", i), 50cm, 50cm), graph_plot)
end
```

[image]

Comment: ありがとうございます、もう少しわかりやすく質問を書き換えました。

Comment: ネットワークは例なので、大丈夫です。大変ありがとうございます！